# Scrapy AttributeError: 'Selector' object has no attribute 'extract_first'

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

In crawling the page https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/pull/11272 with Scrapy 1.6, when I select with the selector:

> //div[@class = 'file js-comment-container
>   js-resolvable-timeline-thread-container']
>
> ***if you are using it on your browser or something, don't forget to block JS.***

the result would be something that has no attribute 'extract_first'.

for example running this code will be facing with that err:

```
for code_and_comment in response.xpath(
        "//div[@class = 'file js-comment-container js-resolvable-timeline-thread-container']"):
    if code_and_comment is None:
        print('it is NONE')
    print(code_and_comment.extract_first())
```

I can't understand it, do you know where am I wrong? thanks in advance.

- **NOTE:** yes I know about *robot.text* and even `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False`
- **NOTE2:** I think dynamic JavaScript is not the problem, I've tried that Xpath with my browser with **JavaScript off** and that worked well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why scrapy Xpath can not find what is found by my browser(s) Xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54606174/why-scrapy-xpath-can-not-find-what-is-found-by-my-browsers-xpath)

Comment: @vezunchik it is not, that is my question too.

Comment: I couldn't find the class "file js-comment-container js-resolvable-timeline-thread-container" but only the class "file js-comment-container js-resolvable-timeline-thread-container has-inline-notes". Did you forget to mention the "has-inline-notes" on your question or forgot to put it on your code?

Comment: @daniboy000 no, I think you are using JavaScript. Scrapy doesn't work with JS. when you see the page with JS blocked then I think you will find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that in your code `code_and_comment` is already a *single* Selector, so there's no point in having `extract_first`. It only works on a list of Selectors (which is what you get from `response.xpath(...)`).

You can just do the following:

```
for code_and_comment in response.xpath(
        "//div[@class = 'file js-comment-container js-resolvable-timeline-thread-container']"):
    if code_and_comment is None:
        print('it is NONE')
    print(code_and_comment.extract())
```